# JavaScript returns different date in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, gmt

I'm working with jQuery datepicker and in Internet Explorer 11 the same date (2017/Aug/12) appears twice and the following (13) doesn't exist. Checking the console I found the following difference between IE11 and Chrome.

Chrome

```
var a = new Date(2017,07,13)
```

> Returns `Sun Aug 13 2017 01:00:00 GMT-0300 (CLST)`

IE11

```
var a = new Date(2017,07,13)
```

> Returns = `Sat Aug 12 2017 23:00:00 GMT-0400 (CLST)`

So in IE11 I can't ask for 2017, Aug, 13.

This is because in that day my country change the timezone, but just it's wrong in IE11.

Some idea how fix that?

Edit
 -
I found the root of the issue, in some place we hace the next line:

> day.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

and that broke the Date Object and change the 13 of August to 12, I dont know why yet.

Comment: Specify `12` for the hour, if you're only interested in the date. But `<input type="date" />` makes date pickers obsolete ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The lack of support from browsers does not....

Comment: @epascarello ... [Granted](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). I naively assumed that if Edge had it, other browsers did too. Come on Firefox...

Comment: Sadly support lacks http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: I'm guessing that if you did `a.getUTCDate()` on both you'd get the same value...

Comment: Finally I use this for that case: day.setHours(day.getHours() + 2); so i get the date Sat Aug 12 2017 23:00:00 GMT-0400 (CLST) and I add 2 hours. Now this is working, but I dont know if exist a better solution, because this will be a fix to rewritte every year :(

Comment: Try supplying zeros for the missing Date constructor parameters.

Comment: I found the root of the issue, in some place we hace the next line: day.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); and that broke the Date Object and change the 13 of August to 12, I dont know why yet.

Comment: @Jordan If you provide a working code snippet so that the problem was easily reproduced, it would be easier to help.

Comment: @Mic I have this line var momentDate = moment(model.get("value"), model.get("dateFormat").toUpperCase());    model.get("value") returns "13/08/2017"  but If I ask for the final value of momentDate is Sat Aug 12 2017 At 23:00